# How can I write a makefile for a custom bash command with a Perl library

Tags: bash, perl, makefile

I wrote a bash command that uses an extensive perl module library. I know that I can install a custom bash command in `usr/bin` simply enough, but I have never had dependencies for a command before.

My makefile, for better or worse, looks like this

```
install:
    cp program.pl /usr/bin/program -f -v
    chmod +x /usr/bin/program -v
```

it's short, but I don't really need to compile anything. program.pl is a short perl script that uses `Getopt::Long` to interact with the module. I have been installing the module separately using MakeMaker as documented [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils::MakeMaker).

my file structure feels a bit overkill for how simple the command should be, but due to how MakeMaker works, it ended up like this

```
program/
    program.pl
    makefile
    perl/
        Makefile.PL
        MANIFEST
        lib/
            Program/
                Package01.pm
                Package02.pm
                Package03.pm
```

and, instead of running a recursive make in the root directory, I have been running make in *both*
places, which I know isn't right (while also being annoying).

I see that all these modules just wind up in `/usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0/Program` but I'd rather it be a little more portable than putting it there myself in my root makefile. What is the correct way to do this? I would like to make this command public eventually and I don't want to mess up an install

Comment: Don't fiddle with `/usr/bin`, unless you know what are you doing, or you are are developing a new version of the operating system. If you wrote a program which should be available for every user, you could consider it putting it somewhere below `/opt`.

Comment: Is this a bundle? Is `program.pl` released with `Program::PackageXX.pm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like program.pl and Program::PackageXX.pm are a bundle.

If so, you should Perl's installer to install not just the modules but the script.

```
Makefile.PL
MANIFEST
bin/
   program.pl
lib/
   App/
      Program.pm
      Program/01.pm
      Program/02.pm
      Program/03.pm
```

`Makefile.PL`:

```perl
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings

use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
 
WriteMakefile(
   NAME          => 'App::Program',
   VERSION_FROM  => 'lib/App/Program.pm',
   ABSTRACT_FROM => 'lib/App/Program.pm',
   AUTHOR        => 'Name E<lt>name[at]cpan.orgE<gt>',
   PREREQ_PM     => { ... },
   EXE_FILES     => [ 'bin/program.pl' ],
   ...,
);
```

(App::... is the preferred namespace for such things.)

Then, simply install the distro as normal.

```bash
perl Makefile.PL
make test
make install
```

This will install the script in the dir given by

```bash
perl -V:installsitescript
```

It should already be in your PATH. If not, add it.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you can just run the command while adding the path to the libraries it needs. Inside the top level *Makefile*, you would run:

```
perl -Iperl/lib program.pl
```

There are various other ways to set the [library search path](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-(@INC)-at-runtime?) for Perl.

The trick might be that your local Perl module needs other modules, and that those are specified in the *Makefile.PL*. You can install those locally with the help of [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib):

```
% perl -Mlocal::lib
PATH="/Users/brian/perl5/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"; export PATH;
PERL5LIB="/Users/brian/perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB:+:${PERL5LIB}}"; export PERL5LIB;
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/Users/brian/perl5${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT:+:${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT}}"; export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT;
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/Users/brian/perl5\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/brian/perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
```

Those are the default values, but you can specify your own base:

```
% perl -Mlocal::lib=/Users/brian/Dev/perl-lib
Attempting to create directory /Users/brian/Dev/perl-lib
PATH="/Users/brian/Dev/perl-lib/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"; export PATH;
PERL5LIB="/Users/brian/Dev/perl-lib/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB:+:${PERL5LIB}}"; export PERL5LIB;
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/Users/brian/Dev/perl-lib${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT:+:${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT}}"; export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT;
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/Users/brian/Dev/perl-lib\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/brian/Dev/perl-lib"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
```

Adjust those values for what you need, put them in your environment, and `cpan` should respect them:

```
 % cd perl && cpan .
```

If you don't mind installing the dependencies in your home directory rather the project directory, don't set any env vars. `cpan`'s `-I` switch will use `local::lib` for you and create and install into `~/perl5/lib`:

```
 % cd perl && cpan -I .
```

Inside your program, pull in `local::lib` and it should figure it out:

```
use local::lib;
```

Or use a relative path:

```
use local::lib 'perl-lib';
```